# Drawing a line between 2 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to draw a line between 2 divs. I currently use jQuery.

The following is my HTML code. I need to draw a line from the div with id `friend1` to the div with id `friend2`.

```
<div style="top:30px;left:95px" id="friend1" original-title="Rafael Rosenberg1">
    <a href="./profile.php?id=1"><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/100000796250125/picture" border="0" height="50" width="50"/></a>
</div> 
<div style="top:30px;left:250px" id="friend2" original-title="Rafael Rosenberg2">
    <a href="./profile.php?id=1"><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/100000796250125/picture" border="0" height="50" width="50"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Drawing lines in DHTML is not an easy thing to do. You might want to consider using a graphics library like SVG or a canvas element.

Its hard for us to help you without more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a small library that can draw a line together with jQuery:

http://www.openstudio.fr/Library-for-simple-drawing-with.html

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

So there are a lot of ways of drawing on a document and it really depends on your actual need.

**Plain Old DHTML**

It's difficult to draw on a plain HTML document. CSS3 provides some solutions, as you can rotate and I believe it has more transparency features.

But, you COULD create a div that is the length of the distance between the two points (which you can get by your positioning - top right bottom left). Fill this div with a background color and give it some width. Position one end of the div at your first point, then figure out the angle to the second point (also using positioning and some trigonometry), and use CSS3 to rotate the div into position.

Needless to say, techniques like this are cumbersome.

**SVG**

Vector graphics embedded in your document. You can draw lines easily and apply rotations, as well as add image elements. This would probably be the easiest solution WITH CAVEATS:

1. SVG is not well supported or documented, so there is a learning curve. Browser support for SVG seems to be increasing, however. IE just started supporting it in version 9.
2. SVG is an embedded technology and exists in some "viewbox" on your page. So, if you want this to be happening inline with regular HTML elements, it will be more difficult. However, SVG does provide functions that map its internal coordinate system to screen pixels, so it's also doable.

**Canvas**

Canvas is raster-based graphics embedded in your document. It's good for images, a bit harder for lines, but totally doable given some of the libraries out there. Like SVG, browser support is limited but growing every day, and it also is difficult to interact with the rest of the page in an inline way.

**WebGL**

OpenGL (3D) for the web. Probably way too heavy for you, but I'll list it for completeness.

Comment: Hmm I just came across this incredible library that uses JQuery and canvas: http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html

Answer (score 1):

here's a [link](https://gist.github.com/alojzije/11127839) to a gist that uses javascript (jquery) to draw a path (and redraw it in case of window resizing) between any 2 html elements.

[demo](https://gist.github.com/alojzije/11127839#file-demo-png)

Comment: This is an amazing library! Thanks for sharing!